# maven deploy does not work the way it is supposed to. Or am i wrong?

Tags: maven, deployment

Got a simple task upon: `mvn deploy` copy final artifact org.foo.MyProject_1.2.3.war to /tomcat/webapps/myproject.war

Set up pom according to the maven docs:

```
...
<distributionManagement>
        <repository>
                <id>local_tomcat</id>
                <url>/tomcat/webapps</url>
        </repository>
</distributionManagement>
...    
<extensions>
        <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-file</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
        </extension>
</extensions>
...
```

But it didn't work. By some reason wagon tries to create directory /org/foo/MyProject/1.2.3 and fails.

Of course i could utilise tomcat:deploy or ant, but i thought `deploy` was a right choice for deployment.

It appears to me that i mistreated `deploy` plug in. It is just the same as `install` with ability to install artifact on remote repository. Am i right?

If `deploy` is wrong choice what is proper way of transferring/renaming files in maven?
Wagon looks nice though not sure if it can rename files.

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [deploy in the Maven meaning](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) is to put artifacts into a remote repository (usually a repository manager or sometimes Maven central) and **NOT** into containers like Tomcat etc. Furthermore based on the [lifecylce in Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) the deploy phase comes after the install phase which means in other words that the install has already run if you have called mvn deploy.
If you would like to deploy an artifact (usually a war) to Tomcat the [maven-tomcat-plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2/) is the right choice. For doing a kind of integration tests the [cargo2-maven-plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) might be a better solution.

Comment: thanx for the reply. now i see that my quick assumption was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The deploy task is normally used to deploy the artifact(s) built by your project into a remote repository, for others to download.

If you want to upload your war built by your project use the plugins like http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/deployment.html or equivalent.